# Unable to run kubectl from ansible

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, kubectl

I'm trying to run a kubectl command from ansible.
Basically the command will tell me if at least one pod is running from a deployment.

```
kubectl get deploy sample-v1-deployment -o json -n sample | jq '.status.conditions[] | select(.reason == "MinimumReplicasAvailable") | .status' | tr -d '"'
```

I tried to run it from a playbook but I'm getting

> Unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout

This is my playbook:

```
- hosts: master
  gather_facts: no
  become: true

  tasks:
    - name: test command
      shell: kubectl get deploy sample-v1-deployment -o json -n sample | jq '.status.conditions[] | select(.reason == "MinimumReplicasAvailable") | .status' | tr -d '"'
      register: result
```

This is the output from ansible:

```
changed: [k8smaster01.test.com] => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "kubectl get deploy sample-v1-deployment -o json -n sample | jq '.status.conditions[] | select(.reason == \"MinimumReplicasAvailable\") | .status' | tr -d '\"'",
    "delta": "0:00:10.507704",
    "end": "2019-04-02 20:59:17.882277",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "kubectl get deploy sample-v1-deployment -o json -n sample | jq '.status.conditions[] | select(.reason == \"MinimumReplicasAvailable\") | .status' | tr -d '\"'",
            "_uses_shell": true,
            "argv": null,
            "chdir": null,
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "removes": null,
            "stdin": null,
            "warn": true
        }
    },
    "rc": 0,
    "start": "2019-04-02 20:59:07.374573",
    "stderr": "Unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout",
    "stderr_lines": [
        "Unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout"
    ],
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": []
}
```

I can run the command manually on the master server without problems. I was also able to use k8s module to create different things on my kubernetes cluster.
I know there is a kubectl module on ansible, could it be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have `$KUBECONFIG` set in your environment, say for example in your `~/.bash_profile`? That would cause an interactive version to differ from an ansible ssh session. You can pretty easily find out by running `- shell: kubectl config view` right before your existing kubectl to see what config -- and more importantly what `context` kubectl is using under ansible

Comment: Also, you didn't ask this, but you can remove the need for that final `tr -d` by telling `jq` to return the [raw value](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq) using `jq -r`

Comment: I was able to run the kubectl config view from ansible and from the kubernetes server and both had the same information.

Comment: I also tried to run it like /usr/bin/kubectl --kubeconfig=/root/.kube/config get deploy sample-v1-deployment -n sample and got the same error.

Comment: Would very much recommend this instead: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/k8s_module.html.

Comment: You say that you can run the command manually, but are you able to run it as the same user that the Ansible task runs as?

Answer (score 2):

I found a couple of workarounds.
One was to use the k8s_facts module

```
- name: Ensure running application
  k8s_facts:
    namespace: sample
    kind: Pod
    label_selectors:
      - app=sample-v1-app
  register: pod_list
  until: pod_list.resources[0].status.phase == 'Running'
  delay: 10
  retries: 3
```

Its simple and gets the works done.

The second workaround was to use the raw module instead of shell or command

```
- name: Get running status
  raw: kubectl get deploy sample-v1-deployment -o json -n sample | jq -r '.status.conditions[] | select(.reason == "MinimumReplicasAvailable") | .status'
```

I'm not sure about using raw. It looks like a hammer for a simple task.
But reading about the module makes me think this problem is related with the syntax (quotes, double quotes, |) more than the command it self.

> Executes a low-down and dirty SSH command, not going through the
>   module subsystem. This is useful and should only be done in a few
>   cases. A common case is installing python on a system without python
>   installed by default. Another is speaking to any devices such as
>   routers that do not have any Python installed.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can connect to your kube-apiserver on the master from a shell, but not from ansible. The error message indicates differences in the kubeconfig.

You can see the kube-apiserver endpoint configured on your `~/.kube/config` like this:

```
$ kubectl config view --minify -o jsonpath='{.clusters[].cluster.server}'
```

It's typically something like this: `https://<servername>:6443`. You can try running the command from ansible to see if you get the same kube-apiserver.

Another thing is you can try is to print the value of the `KUBECONFIG` env variable from ansible to see if it's set to something different from `~/.kube/config`

Hope it helps!

Comment: I was able to run the command through ansible and on the server with the same output. https://master:8443

Comment: it's an env issue, that's why raw works, because it's a clean command and just picking up whatever is in your `~/.kube/config`

Answer (score 0):

You were probably able to solve this issue but since I also faced it today, I would like to let you know that I was able to solve it by defining 'become: false' under my task that was related to interacting with Kubernetes. My playbook starts with 'become: true', just like yours and I cannot change this since most of the tasks in it need the sudo privilege.

For example, my playbook that ended up working for me was similar to this:

```
---
- hosts: chapter2
  become: yes
  ignore_errors: no
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:

# other tasks before this that require sudo privelege

    - name: Start Minikube
      ansible.builtin.shell: minikube start

    - name: Q2. Fetch ROLES
      ansible.builtin.shell: kubectl get nodes -o wide | grep -v ROLES | awk {'print $3'}
      register: ROLES_output
      become: no

    - name: Q3. Save content to file in /home/ansible/Desktop/out.txt
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        content: |
          ROLES={{ ROLES_output.stdout }}
        dest: /home/ansible/Desktop/out.txt

# other tasks after this that require sudo privelege
...
```

Here, I added `become: no` to the `Fetch Roles` task, which is required since minikube uses Docker that is not to be used with sudo priveleges.